# Problema na Requisição Ajax - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

Boa tarde,

Tenho esse código abaixo simples utilizando js porém ele me retorna o erro que está no print abaixo:

Obs:Estou utilizando CodeIgniter 3.0.10, AJAXm jQuery 3.0.0 Minifed e Bootstrap 4

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo:*

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                var base = $("#base_url").val();
                $('#telefone').mask('(99) 99999-9999');

            jQuery("#form-registrar-estilo").submit(function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                var email_validar = $("#email").val();

                for (let el of jQuery('#form-registrar-estilo input')) {
                        if (el.value == "") el.classList.add("error");
                        else el.classList.remove("error");
                    }


                if (!jQuery('#form-registrar-estilo input.error').length) {
                        jQuery.ajax({
                        url:  base + "painel/cadastrar/valida_email",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {email:email},
                        dataType: "json",

                        success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }


                    })
                };
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro está no valor do `data:` do Ajax:

```
data: {email:email},
```

Deveria ser:

```
data: {email:email_validar},
```

Ao usar a variável `email` como valor do argumento `email:`, está selecionando o elemento input com o `id#email` em vez do valor do campo, e com isso causando um erro no jQuery na hora de tratar o `data:`, pois `email`, se não foi declarado antes, é uma variável global referente ao elemento com `id` do mesmo nome.